# \ForEachX and string concatenation

Tags: loops, strings

I'm writing a class where I have an arbitrary number of strings that I'd like to concatenate, then loop over and typeset using `\ForEachX` from the `forarray` package. If I define a command to add to a string, something like:

```
\newcommand{\addtostring}[1]{\expandafter\def\expandafter\teststring\expandafter{\teststring {, }#1}}
\addtostring{A string}
\addtostring{to break}
```

And then try to break on comma, `\ForEachX` doesn't seem to recognise the commas to break on.

If instead, I define a command containing a similar string, there's no problem (see the MWE below). I suspect this has something to do with the `\expandafter` commands, but my understanding of how this command works is pretty fuzzy.

How can I set this up so that my `\addtostring` command allows an arbitrary number of comma-separated tokens to be strung together into something I can split on the comma with `\ForEachX`?

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forarray}

\newcommand{\teststring}{}
\newcommand{\addtostring}[1]{\expandafter\def\expandafter\teststring\expandafter{\teststring {, }#1}}
\addtostring{A string}
\addtostring{to break}

\newcommand{\anotherteststring}{, Another string, to break}

\begin{document}

 Test string: \teststring

 \begin{itemize}
  \ForEachX{,}{\item \thislevelitem}{\teststring}
  \ForEachX{,}{\item \thislevelitem}{\anotherteststring}
 \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I know this example is a bit artificial. `\addtostring` is a stub for a command that takes two arguments and produces a formatted string with them.

Also, I'm aware that the way I have this code set up I'll have an extra empty token at the start of the string. I can deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the braces around the comma:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forarray}

\newcommand{\teststring}{}
\newcommand{\addtostring}[1]{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\teststring\expandafter{\teststring,#1}%
}
\addtostring{A string}
\addtostring{to break}

\newcommand{\anotherteststring}{, Another string, to break}

\begin{document}

 Test string: \teststring

 \begin{itemize}
  \ForEachX{,}{\item \thislevelitem}{\teststring}
  \ForEachX{,}{\item \thislevelitem}{\anotherteststring}
 \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A better implementation with `expl3` that uses sequences. The optional argument to `\addtostring` is for a “string name” (by default the name is “default”). Similarly for the optional argument to `\usestring`. Note that this has no side effect with commas at the beginning.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtostring}{O{default}m}
 {
  \seq_if_exist:cF { g_goblin_string_#1_seq }
   {
    \seq_new:c { g_goblin_string_#1_seq }
   }
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_goblin_string_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\usestring}{O{default}m}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:cn { g_goblin_string_#1_seq } { #2 ##1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addtostring{A string}
\addtostring{to break}

\addtostring[new]{Another string}
\addtostring[new]{to break}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\usestring{\item}
\usestring[new]{\item}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]